# Downloading google play console statistics via gsutils & google cloud storage

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, zsh, google-play-console, gsutil

I am trying to pull data from the google playstore console through the cli.

The documentation that I am using as a reference is [this](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6135870?hl=en&ref_topic=7071935#zippy=%2Cdownload-reports-using-a-command-line-tool%2Cinstalls).

I have retrieved my cloud storage URI from the playstore console and used the command:

`gsutil cp -r gs://pubsite_prod_xxxxxx/stats/installs/installs_com.my.package_2021* .`

I get an error message like this:

zsh: no matches found: gs://pubsite_prod_xxxxx/stats/installs/installs_com.my.package_2021*

I am trying to understand what the issue could be. Any pointers would be of great help.

Other details:

1. Though my playstore account is two or three years old, I just created my google cloud platform account. (So, could the issue be that there are no reports written onto my bucket, though there is a URI mentioned on the play console?)
2. I am unable to see this bucket through the google cloud platform console.  The list of buckets are empty. (I am however not sure whether I am looking at the right place). Attaching a screenshot of the project on the console that I am looking into.
   [screenshot - empty list of buckets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FUaKo.png)

Comment: I have seen that you are using zsh shell. Looks like an [issue](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gsutil/issues/499) related to it, have you tried with bash shell instead?

Comment: Wow! Thanks, I am able to download it now. :) Used bash this time.

Comment: I developed the answer, glad to hear that :)

Comment: Thank you. Tried the second option to escape the special characters and I could successfully download the same once again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an issue related to [ZSH](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gsutil/issues/499#:%7E:text=This%20is%20an,issue%20as%20closed.) You may could change your shell, via `sudo chsh --shell=/bin/bash $USER` will change the shell field in `/etc/passwd`

Or you may use `'` around a special character to escape the special character in order to let [the shell recognize it.](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gsutil/issues/471) like:

```
gsutil cp -r 'gs://pubsite_prod_xxxxxx/stats/installs/installs_com.my.package_2021*' .
```